# Crosswalk Crash: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.onTouchEvent

Tags: android, crosswalk

Of course understanding that Crosswalk is no longer being updated, I have encountered a pretty notable issue that I don't really know what to do with. Ever since I updated my Android apps' Crosswalk from 14 to 23, I've been seeing an alarmingly large volume of Google Play crash reports related to org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.onTouchEvent on a broad array of Android versions and devices. I've looked around Google/StackOverflow with no success, and to be honest don't even know where to start in diagnosing the issue since I haven't been able to replicate it myself. A sample stack trace is below.

Any recommendations? Even tips on paths to move forward to figuring out what is going on would be great. I would rather not strip Crosswalk from my app since I do have a non-insignificant number of Android <5.0 users.

Thanks!

> java.lang.RuntimeException:    at
>   org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.onTouchEvent(XWalkView.java:1689)   at
>   android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10011)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2344)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2675)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2675)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2675)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:437)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1814)
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3070)   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:386)
>   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10251)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4659)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4517)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4028)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4053)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4202)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4061) 
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4259)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4033)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4053)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4061) 
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4033)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6459)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6427)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6381)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6562)
>   at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:216)
>   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method:0)   at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question, but since this question is the top google result, I'll add it for reference: This might be related: https://github.com/infil00p/cordova-crosswalk-engine/issues/79